# Connect A-Frame to BLE devices on any smartphones

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, aframe, android-ble, ios-bluetooth

I have an application that uses [A-Frame](https://aframe.io/) to display an animation in "VR". I say "VR" because there is not interaction from the user, I use VR-headset and VR-technologies to focus the user on an animation. The user is passive and will receive stimuli.

I need to connect two vibrating devices ([like this one](http://www.mi.com/en/miband/)) in bluetooth to the webapp, and make them vibrate when needed.

This application should run on any smartphone on classical browsers.
I saw that BLE/Smartphone usage from web-app is pretty new ([medium](https://medium.com/@urish/is-now-a-good-time-to-start-using-web-bluetooth-hint-yes-yes-it-is-99e998d7b9f6), [custom browser](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/webble/id1193531073), and [this](http://forum.espruino.com/conversations/298547/)).

How can I access if this will work as I don't have iOS and android devices at my disposal?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to try out *Web Bluetooth* connectivity without having an iOS or Android device.
*Web Bluetooth* [is enabled without flags in Chrome Desktop on Chrome OS and Mac OS](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/gh-pages/implementation-status.md) and enabled by default in version >61.

Chrome on Linux and Windows require a flag to be set (see link above).

So, you should be able to use a regular desktop computer that has Bluetooth hardware built in to experiment with the technology without using a smartphone. [Only Chrome, Opera and Samsung Internet](https://caniuse.com/#feat=web-bluetooth) implements the Web Bluetooth API as of today (December 2017).

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! I didnt know that regular desktop browser can use BLE. This will be helpful for testing purpose. But how do I "guarantee" that, once it worked on my PC, it will work on a iOS or Android device? Because web bluetooth is available on iOS and Android?

Comment: In theory if it works on your desktop it should work on mobile in the same browser, as long as both browsers support the feature you are making use of (see document in first link).

But I fear there is no guarantee for it to work, Web Bluetooth is (still) a non-standard and experimental technology after all. The only guarantee would be to test on the actual physical device you are targeting.